# SQL query to find out the peak of number of video streams

Tags: sql, time-series, max

I have got the following SQL question in a job interview:

```
Table:
  customer_id,
  video_id,
  start_time,
  end_time
```

The question is to find the peak time of streaming video. The interviewer did not accept going with an hour window.

I, personally, would do it in the code sliding a one-second window through the time and find the max, but I cannot write for every second a SQL CASE statement.

Would appreciate any hint?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the peak, then break the data into "two" -- and do a cumulative sum.

If you just want the peak for *all* videos:

```
with t as (
      select start_time as time, 1 as inc
      from <table> t
      union all
      select end_time, -1 as inc
      from <table> t
     )
select time, sum(inc),
       sum(sum(inc)) over (order by time) as concurrent
from t
group by time
order by concurrent desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

This can be modified to get the peak for each video as well.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much, I was also thinking the same direction turning times into  on/off switches, which you did very nicely through 1 and -1. sum(inc) to count for duplicate times was something that I was not even thinking about! Took me a little to digest, but it is a great solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting Challenge. 
You didn't provide DDL and sample data, so I can't test it, but the general direction I would go is to create a derived table for every minute within the desired range, join that back to the table you described based on the minute within the streaming range, and then count the rows. If using PostgreSQL for example, and limiting to January 2018, you can do something along the lines of:

```
WITH All_Minutes
AS
(
SELECT Actual_Minute
FROM generate_series('2018-01-01 00:00'::timestamp, '2018-02-01 00:00', interval '00:01:00') AS TS(Actual_Minute)
),
SELECT Actual_Minute, COUNT(*) AS Number_Of_Streams
FROM   Your_Table AS YT
       INNER JOIN
       All_Minutes AS AM
       ON AM.Actual_Minute BETWEEN YT.start_Time and YT.end_time
GROUP BY Actual_Minute
ORDER BY Number_Of_Streams DESC      
LIMIT 1;
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time, I will check out this solution in details and let you know, but generally coming up with a time-window, which I had in mind initially as well, is not an ideal way of approaching this problem. This is because during one minute many short video streaming spikes could come and go so that you cannot catch the real peak.  @Gordon Linoff answer is indeed the perfect answer. Essentially translating a video-start to 1 and video-end to -1 makes it possible to find the max peak exactly.